# Oracle trigger doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, identifier

I'm trying to get this code sorted, and it does compile, but when I test by deleting a record if gives: 
Invalid Identifier

The error is probably in the :old part, but I just can't figure it out.

This is my code.

```
create or replace trigger t_OnDeleteCategory
create or replace trigger t_OnDeleteCategory
before delete on Categorie
for each row
declare
 v_textMail  varchar2(2000);
 v_emailAdres MailAbonnee.emailAdres%type;
 v_Voornaam MailAbonnee.voornaam%type;
 v_Achternaam MailAbonnee.Achternaam%type;
 c_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
 v_sql varchar2(2000);
 v_categorienaam categorie.naam%type;
begin
 v_categorienaam := :old.naam;
--1) mailbericht verzenden
v_sql := 'select voornaam, achternaam, emailAdres from MailAbonnee where id in (select mailAbonneeID from CategorieAbonnement where categorieNaam = v_categorienaam)';
open c_cursor for v_sql;
loop
    fetch c_cursor into v_Voornaam, v_Achternaam, v_emailAdres;
    exit when c_cursor%notfound;
    v_textMail := 'Beste ' || v_Voornaam || ' ' || v_Achternaam || ', uw abonnement is opgeheven voor Categorie '|| v_categorienaam || '.';
    sendMailAbonnee(v_textMail, v_emailadres);
end loop;
--2) verwijder alle abonnementen
delete from CategorieAbonnement where categorieNaam = v_categorienaam;
--3) pas alle nieuwsberichten aan
update Nieuwsbericht set categorieNaam = '' where categorieNaam = v_categorienaam;
 end;
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use dynamic SQL in your trigger?  It does not appear to be necessary here.  But perhaps you've simplified the problem in order to post here and there is some reason in your actual code that you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Can you show us the table structure for `Categorie` and`MailAbonnee`?

Comment: You have `create or replace trigger t_OnDeleteCategory` twice at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @JustinCave suggests, you have a problem with your dynamic SQL. `v_categorienaam` is a variable yet it's in the string of your SQL. Remove the dynamic SQL and your problem will go away.

In addition, you can simplify your code a lot by using a cursor for loop, something like:

```
create or replace trigger t_OnDeleteCategory
before delete on Categorie
for each row
declare
  v_textMail  varchar2(2000);
begin
  --1) mailbericht verzenden
  for c in (
    select voornaam, achternaam, emailAdres
    from MailAbonnee
    where id in (
      select mailAbonneeID from CategorieAbonnement where categorieNaam = :old.naam
    )
  ) loop
    v_textMail := 'Beste ' || c.voornaam || ' ' || c.achternaam || ', uw abonnement is opgeheven voor Categorie '|| c.naam || '.';
    sendMailAbonnee(v_textMail, c.emailadres);
  end loop;
  --2) verwijder alle abonnementen
  delete from CategorieAbonnement where categorieNaam = :old.naam;
  --3) pas alle nieuwsberichten aan
  update Nieuwsbericht set categorieNaam = '' where categorieNaam = :old.naam;
end;
```

Comment: In addition, you can remove steps 2 and 3 by making your database foreign keys `on delete cascade` and `on delete set null` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
v_sql := 'select voornaam, achternaam, emailAdres from MailAbonnee where id in (select mailAbonneeID from CategorieAbonnement where categorieNaam = v_categorienaam)';
```

.... you're referring to `v_categorienaam`, but that isn't a variable in scope when the dynamic SQL is executed. You should be using a bind variable:

```
v_sql := 'select voornaam, achternaam, emailAdres from MailAbonnee where id in (select mailAbonneeID from CategorieAbonnement where categorieNaam = :v_categorienaam)';
```

and then

```
open c_cursor for v_sql using v_categorienaam;
```

But there doesn't seem to be any reason for this to be dynamic at all, as others have already pointed out. You can get rid of `v_sql` and just do:

```
open c_cursor for
  select voornaam, achternaam, emailAdres
  from MailAbonnee
  where id in (
    select mailAbonneeID
    from CategorieAbonnement
    where categorieNaam = v_categorienaam;
```

Which is easier to format and read, and can be validated at parse/compilation time, rather than giving you any potential errors at runtime. Colin's version is even simpler; you're not gaining anything from the explicit fetch.